# How to properly add a custom property in a specific type

Tags: symfony, elastica

In a search field, i want to suggest to users cities where same names are sorting by the number of restaurants found (in descending order).

Therefore i want to add a custom field which would help me to sort similar city names (i.e. 'Washington' => in arkansas, illinois, california, etc) by their number of restaurants.

I've read the following [cookbook](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook/custom-properties.md) to add a custom property but my lack of knowledge in sf and elastica is preventing me from putting the listener in the correct place.

Let's say i have a `city` and a `restaurant` type, configure like this :

```
city:
  mappings:
    name: ~
    location: { type: geo_point }
restaurant:
  mappings:
    name: ~
    location: { type: geo_point }
```

I know that for each city added in my index, i should *geolocate* every restaurant nearby it (~ 5miles for example). How should i do it ?

context :

- php 5.6
- symfony 2.3
- friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle 3.1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll respond to my question if it can help :

If you want to geolocate (or do any other operations) on a specific type, you just need to filter it :

```
// assume correct namespaces are used...
class CustomPropertyListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function addCustomProperty(TransformEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->getDocument()->getType() === 'city') {

            $coord = $event->getDocument()->get('location');
            // call to the service which can find restaurants 
            $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.restaurant');            
            $filter = new GeoDistance('location', $coord, '5mi');

            $all = new Query(new MatchAll());
            $query = new Filtered($all, $filter);
            $entities = $finder->find($query);

            $document->set('numRestaurants', count($entities));
        }
    }
}
```

The `$container` is defined in the `services` definition file. For example in YAML :

```
    acme.listener.custom_property:
    class: AcmeBundle\EventListener\CustomPropertyListener
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

It should be noted that `elastic` + `elastica-bundle` are poorly documented for such a complex and critical component. Much of the vital infos are scattered through the web or in the code. I hope devs are aware of this !